# index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing

Tags: python, pandas

I've tried these codes. I can't find what i missing.

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3)),index=['a', 'c', 'd'],columns=['Ohio', 'Texas', 'California'])
states = ['Texas', 'Utah', 'California']
frame.reindex(index=['a','b','c','d'],method='ffill',columns=states)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not implemented for non numeric index values, possible solution if not exist missing values in original data:

```
df = frame.reindex(index=['a','b','c','d'], columns=states).ffill()
print (df)
   Texas  Utah  California
a    1.0   NaN         2.0
b    1.0   NaN         2.0
c    4.0   NaN         5.0
d    7.0   NaN         8.0
```

Comment: seems like a similar prob: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285508/valueerror-index-must-be-monotonic-increasing-or-decreasing

Answer (score 0):

`reindex` and `method=ffill` does implement for string. However, it requires the dataframe/series index and columns must be monotonic increase or decrease when you use `method` option. `frame.columns` is non-monotonic, so it fails.

Let try this example by making columns of `frame` is in lexical order. `method=ffill` works fine when both `index` and `column` are monotonic even though they are strings:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3)),index=['a', 'c', 'd'],columns=['California', 'Ohio', 'Texas'])
states = ['Texas', 'Utah', 'California']
frame.reindex(index=['a','b','c','d'],method='ffill',columns=states)

Out[876]:
   Texas  Utah  California
a      2     2           0
b      2     2           0
c      5     5           3
d      8     8           6
```

If your `index` and `columns` are strings and not monotonic, you need to call `.ffill`, `.bfill` or `.fillna` outside after of `reindex`

**Note**: this constraint on `method` option is also applied to numeric `index`. Just try create a dataframe with numeric non-monotonic index, reindex with `method` will return the same error.

---

from docs:

> method : {None, ‘backfill’/’bfill’, ‘pad’/’ffill’, ‘nearest’}
>   Method to use for filling holes in reindexed DataFrame. Please note: this is only applicable to DataFrames/Series with a monotonically increasing/decreasing index.