# reindexing error when using method='ffill'

Tags: python, pandas

ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing 
[Jupyter Notebook Image][1]

> I am practicing the above code snippet from the book ***python for data analysis by Wes McKinney***

I create a DataFrame like this

```
frame=DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3,3)), index=['a','c','d'], columns=['Ohio','Texas','California'])
```

when I try to reindex it like this:

```
states=['Texas','Utah','California']
frame.reindex(index=['a','b','c','d'],method='ffill', columns=states)
```

why is ValueError being raised?

Comment: Need more information. How does the original dataframe look like?

Comment: Could you add a question in the question line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285508/valueerror-index-must-be-monotonic-increasing-or-decreasing)

Comment: so, what do i do?

Comment: Because the `columns` index is not monotonic, as the error message says.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
frame.reindex(index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], columns=states).ffill()
```